# Java-How to restrict input number range with is Document Filter?

Tags: java

Thank you for your help!
I'm using a Documentfilter to restrict the range of input. In my code I can restrict the input to be decimal. But how can I restrict the range of number as well? 
For example, for textfield1:1-3, for textfield2:10-80?

Here's my code:

```
    class MyIntFilter2 extends DocumentFilter {

    @Override
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset,
            String string, AttributeSet attr)
            throws BadLocationException {
        try {
            if (string.equals(".")
                    && !fb.getDocument()
                            .getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength())
                            .contains(".")) {
                super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
                return;
            }
            Double.parseDouble(string);
            super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length,
            String text, AttributeSet attrs)
            throws BadLocationException {
        try {
            if (text.equals(".")
                    && !fb.getDocument()
                            .getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength())
                            .contains(".")) {
                super.insertString(fb, offset, text, attrs);
                return;
            }
            Double.parseDouble(text);
            super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use JSpinner with numberSpinnerModel

Answer (score 1):

After your parsed the `String` into a `Double`, add a validation of the `Double` to make sure it is in the range you want. If it isn't, just `return` and if it is, call `super.insert` or `replace`. You'll need a `DocumentFilter` for each range or one that takes the range in his constructor.

Something like this assuming you include the min and max value into the range

```
class MyIntFilter2(Double prMin, Double prMax) extends DocumentFilter {
  private Double min;
  private Double max;

...

@Override
public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset,
        String string, AttributeSet attr)
        throws BadLocationException {

 ...

 Double value = Double.parseDouble(string);
 if (value.compareTo(max) <= 0 && value.compareTo(min) >= 0) {
   super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
 } else {
   return;
 }
```